# enabling notifications for facebook graph

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to use facebook notifications using graph. But it says i dont have the correct permissions. This is the url I used to try to get notifications on during permission acceptance. but its not showing up

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=523691235&redirect_uri=http://apps.facebook.com/my_app&manage_notifications=1
```

am I passing the correct parameter ?? How do I get facebook to ask the user to allow me to send notifications to them.

Comment: You need to request the permissions. No where in your Oauth request do you specify permissions your app needs

Comment: your saying that I have the parameter in the wrong position ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must request a `manage_notifications` within the `scope` parameter of the authentication. Otherwise it will not work.

If you are unsure if you have done so, take that `access_token` and run it in the [debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to see if its connected to a user as well as possessing the correct permissions.

Comment: just to follow up with your answer. example would be `&scope=email,manage_notifications`